# server not receving request by Ip

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, server

I've got an issue where my IIS 7 C# server is configured but only reciving requests only when i use http://localhost:6547/ and not when i change the localhost to my own ip.
My question is : how do i make the server actually 'listen' to my port and recevie and return requests.
facts that might help:

- im using Windows 7
- i gave iUsr and IIS_USER permissions to server's directory
- added listening to 6547 port, in both TCP and UDP
- tried disabling the firewall totally, still haven't worked this way.
- when i try using requests, im using the Advanced Rest Client of chrome, either when i try with my ip or with localhost as mentioned before.

I think its something else related to premissions of remote access. my IIS 7 doesnt have permission manager for some reason even though i really added all the IIS related features available in the windows control panel.

If any data is missing i would gladly provide it.

Comment: this sounds like it belongs on [sf]

Comment: hmm. @DanielA.White perhaps u're right, i didnt know about this. i will post my quest there and delete this.

Comment: @DanielA.White perhaps not, i dont see an activity in that web..

Answer (score 1):

You need to confirm that your IIS is bound to all ip's (the * in picture below).
Open IIS Adminstration->click on iis->click on bindings and update appropriately:

[image]

Other leads: https://serverfault.com/questions/148439/how-can-i-control-which-ip-address-iis7-uses